# Exact sequence - proof

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a ring. Prove that a sequence of left $R$-modules and homomorphisms
$$0 \to N_1 \xrightarrow{f} N_2 \xrightarrow{g} N_3$$

is exact if and only if for all left $R$-modules $M$ sequence
$$\hom_R(M, N_1) \xrightarrow{\bar f} \hom_R(M, N_2) \xrightarrow{\bar g} \hom_R(M, N_3) \to 0$$

is an exact sequence of abelian groups, where mappings $\overline{f} : \operatorname{Hom_{R}}(M,N_1)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom_{R}}(M,N_2)$ and $\overline{g} : \operatorname{Hom_{R}}(M,N_2)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom_{R}}(M,N_3)$ are given by formulas $$\overline{f}(\phi)=f \circ \phi$$ and $$\overline{g}(\psi)=f \circ \psi$$

I don't have any idea how to solve this problem. Any help please?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to prove...? Take $M=R$ and you'll see why what you wrote is very strange.

Comment: This is exactly an exercise from my book (in Polish).

Comment: Are you really sure the $\to 0$ is at the end in the second exact sequence, and not at the beginning? To expand on my first comment, if you take $M=R$ you will see that you're trying to prove that $0 \to N_1 \to N_2 \to N_3 \text{ exact} \implies N_1 \to N_2 \to N_3 \to 0 \text{ exact}$, which isn't true...

Answer (score 3):

The statement "$\hom_R(M, N_1) \xrightarrow{\bar f} \hom_R(M, N_2) \xrightarrow{\bar g} \hom_R(M, N_3)$$ \color {red}{\to 0}$" in your question is false. you can see [*here*](https://books.google.com/books?id=e-YlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=hungerford+Conversely,+assume+that+the+Hom+sequence+of+induced+maps+is+exact&source=bl&ots=ztxwEmMAei&sig=MHcol4E35IdSN_JlTITMQPYJCf4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p503VcGnOYTgyQP0hYDQDw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=true), in *Hungerford*'s book "*Algebra*", the right statement and proof:

[image]

Comment: **dear downvoter! can you explain**?

Answer (score 0):

Hom(M, ) is known as a covariant functor (preserves arrows) so your sequence of Hom(M, ) modules should be left exact (0 on the left).